# increasing dimensions in a list

Tags: c#, list

using ...

```
string[] myFiles = Directory.GetFiles(FilePathIn, "*.dat", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

I am getting a list of files returned. Alongside this I want to keep a set of int flags. I am about to do this by creating a tuple list eg `List<Tuple<int, string>>` then looping through myfiles adding each to the tuple list.

Although this will work I wondered if there was a cleaner way to do this? It doesn't have to be a tuple list. It just needs to be an ordered list of the files with a flag

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. The options are clearly numerous. I will have a play around with them and see what works. Just for clarification: The files will be processed in cycles after each cycle some of the files will be dropped off. At the end of the process I list the files in order of best fit matched to worst fit.

Answer (score 0):

Why  you  don't use  dictionary to access an element in  a dictionary it will cost O(1)

```
 Dictionary<int,string> myFilesOrderedDict = new Dictionary<int,string>();
```

Or if  you want to groupfile by an  int as a flag you can do the inverse  as I don't think that the name of the file can be repeated twice

Something like this
      //string will  be the name of  the file

```
 Dictionary<string ,int> myFilesOrderedDict = new Dictionary<string,int>();
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in just iteration then a list of some compound type is the way to go -- you can use a custom `struct` instead of a `Tuple` to increase readability or a custom `class` if you intend for the flags to be mutable later on, but the general idea is the same.

You can also use a `Dictionary<string, int>` of filenames to flags; this has the advantage that it allows quick lookups if you have a filename in hand.

Finally, consider using a [`[Flags]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx) `enum` instead of a bare integer to hold the flags you need.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want to use the data later, I would either map the filenames to the integers (`Dictionary<string, int>`) or the integers to files. I assume two files can have the same "flag", so I would use either a `Dictionary<int, List<string>>` or constuct `IGrouping<int, string>` or `ILookup<int, string>`. It's a shame really that .NET BCL doesn't contain a straightforward mutable Multimap (or Lookup) that you could use like a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx):

```
var filesWithFlags = Directory.GetFiles(..)
                              .Select(f => new {File = f, Flags = 123});
```

And use the result like this:

```
foreach (var fileWithFlags in filesWithFlags)
{
    DoSomethingWith(fileWithFlags.File);
    AndDoSomethingWith(fileWithFlags.Flags);
}
```